# Async IO - reading char from input blocks output

Tags: python, linux, asynchronous, stdout, stdin

Note: this example was tested on a linux terminal emulator, and due to the use of `termios` (which I have no idea if it's cross-platform) it might not work well on other operating systems' terminals.

---

I've been trying to make an "asynchronous" python prompt. What I mean by that is that, while the user is typing an input from a prompt, they can also receive messages, without cancelling the input.

Below is an implementation of it using `asyncio.Queue` and some `termios` flags (sorry in advance for the complexity, I tried to reduce it as much as possible):

```py
import sys, termios, os
import asyncio

def readline(prompt: str = "Input: "):
    # termios stuff to: disable automatic echo so that, when a character is typed, it is not immediately printed on screen
    #                   read a single character from stdin without pressing <Enter> to finish
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    orig_termios = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    new_termios = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    new_termios[3] &= ~(termios.ICANON | termios.ECHO)

    # set to new termios
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, new_termios)

    async def terminput(queue: asyncio.Queue):
        """Get terminal input and send it to the queue."""
        while True:
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1) # read a single char (works because of the termios config)

            if ch == "\n":
                await queue.put(("finish", None)) # `None` here because we won't use the second argument
                await asyncio.sleep(0) # strange workaround so the queues actually work
                continue

            await queue.put(("input", ch))
            await asyncio.sleep(0) # strange workaround so the queues actually work

    async def timedsender(queue: asyncio.Queue):
        """Every 0.5 seconds, send a message to the queue."""
        while True:
            await queue.put(("message", "I'm a message!"))
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    
    async def receiver(queue: asyncio.Queue):
        """Handle the receiving of messages and input characters."""
        # Late decision that I might be able to fix easily - I had to use a list to push characters into on a earlier version of the code. It can be a string now, though.
        input_buffer = []

        sys.stdout.write(prompt)
        sys.stdout.flush()

        def clear_line():
            """Clear the current line.

            There might be an escape code that does this already. Eh, anyways...
            """
            sys.stdout.write("\r")
            sys.stdout.write(" " * os.get_terminal_size().columns)
            sys.stdout.write("\r")
            sys.stdout.flush()

        def redraw_input_buffer():
            """Redraw the input buffer.

            Shows the prompt and what has been typed until now.
            """
            sys.stdout.write(prompt + "".join(input_buffer))
            sys.stdout.flush()

        while True:
            # So, lemme explain what this format is.
            # Each item sent on the queue should be a tuple.
            # The first element is what should be done with the content (such as show message, add to input buffer), and the second element is the content itself.
            kind, content = await queue.get()

            if kind == "message":
                clear_line()
                sys.stdout.write(f"Message -- {content}\n")
                sys.stdout.flush()
                redraw_input_buffer()
            elif kind == "input":
                sys.stdout.write(content)
                sys.stdout.flush()
                input_buffer += content
            elif kind == "finish":
                sys.stdout.write("\n")

                sys.stdout.write(f"INPUT FINISHED :: {repr(''.join(input_buffer))}\n")
                sys.stdout.flush()
                
                input_buffer.clear()
                redraw_input_buffer()
                # continue reading more input lines...
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"Unknown kind: {repr(kind)}")

            queue.task_done()
    
    async def main():
        queue = asyncio.Queue()
    
        senders = [terminput(queue), timedsender(queue)]
        recv = receiver(queue)
        await asyncio.gather(*senders, recv)
    
        await queue.join()
        recv.cancel()

    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    finally:
        # reset to original termios
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, orig_termios)

readline()
```

The main problem at question here is that the queue is only read when a character is typed, and even then, if I don't wait enough time to read the next char with, say, `asyncio.sleep(0.1)`, usually just one message is received in the meantime.

I am not sure if the problem is the queue or some inner workings of the stdin-stdout mechanism (maybe I can't write to stdout while stdin is blocked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out a solution for this problem - setting a max wait time for a character to be input.

At the top of `readline()`:

```py
def readline(prompt: str = "Input: "):
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    orig_termios = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    new_termios = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    new_termios[3] &= ~(termios.ICANON | termios.ECHO)
    
    # the following lines were added:
    new_termios[6][termios.VMIN] = 0 # minimal amount of characters to
    new_termios[6][termios.VTIME] = 1 # a max wait time of 1/10 second
```

When using this directly on C, on timeout the character returned would be of code `170`, but here not even that seems to happen (the read operations from Python might already ignore them).